# Reword tagged questions sidebar

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

I recently pulled up a list of tagged questions via the Interesting Tags box by typing in the tag I was interested in, clicking Add, and then clicking the tag.  When the list of questions appeared, the number of questions indicated in the right sidebar said "X questions tagged."  While I'm certain I don't have enough reputation to actively tag questions, the wording startled me for a moment, making me think that I actually had tagged the questions.

My suggestion is to transpose the words so that it reads "X tagged questions" instead of "X questions tagged."